# Combine 2 regex functions into 1 function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am taking a regex course and to make it easier I have created 2 functions.  The first is for `re.findall` and the second is for `re.search`.  Is there an easy way to combine these 2 functions so I only have one?

```
import re

def ans_findall(num,reg):
    data = open(r'2020_REGEX_COURSE/Ex_Files/regex'+num+'.txt', encoding='utf-8').read()
    data = re.findall(reg,data, re.MULTILINE)
    return data

def ans_search(num,reg):
    data = open(r'2020_REGEX_COURSE/Ex_Files/regex'+num+'.txt', encoding='utf-8').read()
    data = re.search(data, re.MULTILINE)
    return data
```

Comment: And what would the "one" function do? BTW, you are not closing your files. And you are using `r'...'` syntax where it makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first recommendation is to get the code that you want working without using functions. I'll assume here you've done that. I suspect your question is more about how to return two values from a single function.

```
def find_data(filename, pattern):
    with open(filename,'r', encoding='utf-8') as file_handle:
        data = file_handle.read()
    search_result  = re.search( data, pattern, re.MULTILINE)
    findall_result = re.findall(data, pattern, re.MULTILINE)
    return search_result, findall_result

num=str(5)
search_result, findall_result = find_data(
        '2020_REGEX_COURSE/Ex_Files/regex'+num+'.txt', 'someregexhere')
```